# AVL-Tree Implementation in Java

Tags: java, tree

I'm looking for feedback on this AVL tree implementation. Particularly on the overall structure, readability and abstraction. I've tried to keep all AVL specific operations inside the `balancePath` method to allow for easy conversion to a red/black tree with only minor changes to the rest of the code. Are there any further abstractions I could make to simplify the code even further?

```
public class AVLTreeDictionary<K extends Comparable<K>,V> implements Dictionary<K,V>
{
    /* Duplicate keys handling by overwriting value. Null keys
     * unsupported. It is assumed they will not be passed in.
     * Duplicate and null values supported.
     */
    private Node root;
    public AVLTreeDictionary()
    {
        root = null;
    }
    public V insert(K key, V value)
    {
        /* Adds a new entry to the tree. If the key already exists
         * overwrites the value and returns the old value. Performs
         * AVL rebalancing afterwords.
         */
        Path path = getPath(key);
        if(path.child() != null)
        {
            V previous = path.child().value;
            path.child().value = value;
            return previous;
        }
        path.setChild(new Node(key, value));
        path.pop();
        balancePath(path);
        return null;
    }
    public V delete(K key)
    {
        /* Deletes an entry from the tree if it exists.
         * If 0 children: Deletes entry.
         * If 1 child: Replaces entry with child.
         * If 2 children: Randomly selected between successor/predecessor
         * and copies values then deletes succ/pred and replaces it with
         * its one child if it exists. Performs AVL rebalancing afterwords.
         */
        Path path = getPath(key);
        Node node = path.child();
        if(node == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if(node.right == null)
        {
            path.setChild(node.left);
        }
        else if(node.left == null)
        {
            path.setChild(node.right);
        }
        else
        {
            boolean direction = Math.random() >= 0.5;
            path.push(direction);
            while(path.grandChild(!direction) != null)
            {
                path.push(!direction);
            }
            node.key = path.child().key;
            node.value = path.child().value;
            path.setChild(path.grandChild(direction));
        }
        path.pop();
        balancePath(path);
        return null;
    }
    public V search(K key)
    {
        // Standard binary search.
        Node search = root;
        while(search != null)
        {
            int compare = key.compareTo(search.key);
            if(compare == 0)
            {
                return search.value;
            }
            search = search.child(compare > 0);
        }
        return null;
    }
    private Path getPath(K key)
    {
        /* Returns a path from the root to the key specified or the
         * position it would be added in if it does not exist. Includes
         * the root edge.
         */
        Path path = new Path(new Edge(null, false));
        while(true)
        {
            if(path.child() == null)
            {
                return path;
            }
            int compare = key.compareTo(path.child().key);
            if(compare == 0)
            {
                return path;
            }
            path.push(compare > 0);
        }
    }
    private void rotate(Edge edge, boolean direction)
    {
        /* Rotates the child of the edge with its child
         * in the direction specified. It is assumed both the child
         * and grandchild are not null.
         */
        Edge rotate = new Edge(edge.child(), direction);
        edge.setChild(rotate.child());
        rotate.setChild(rotate.grandChild(!direction));
        edge.child().setChild(rotate.parent, !direction);
    }
    private int height(Node node)
    {
        if(node == null)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return node.height;
        }
    }
    private void balancePath(Path path)
    {
        /* Follows a path up the tree performing AVL rebalancing
         * and height updates as needed.
         */
        while(path.peek() != null)
        {
            int previous = path.child().height;
            if(Math.abs(path.child().balance()) > 1)
            {
                boolean direction = path.child().balance() > 0;
                if(path.child().balance() * path.grandChild(direction).balance() < 0)
                {
                    path.push(direction);
                    rotate(path.peek(), !direction);
                    path.pop().grandChild(direction).updateHeight();
                }
                rotate(path.peek(), direction);
                path.grandChild(!direction).updateHeight();
            }
            if(path.pop().child().updateHeight() == previous)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private class Node
    {
        /* This node class has get/set child functions that use a variable
         * to select which child. This allows us to avoid writing duplicate
         * code for the mirror image of operations. The balance of a node
         * refers to the difference in height between the right and left
         * subtrees. A positive balance is right-heavy, negative is left-heavy.
         * False = Left, True = Right.
         */
        public Node left;
        public Node right;
        public K key;
        public V value;
        public int height;
        public Node(K key, V value)
        {
            left = null;
            right = null;
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            height = 0;
        }
        public Node child(boolean direction)
        {
            if(direction)
            {
                return right;
            }
            else
            {
                return left;
            }
        }
        public void setChild(Node child, boolean direction)
        {
            if(direction)
            {
                right = child;
            }
            else
            {
                left = child;
            }
        }
        public int balance()
        {
            return height(right) - height(left);
        }
        public int updateHeight()
        {
            height = Math.max(height(right), height(left)) + 1;
            return height;
        }
    }
    private class Edge
    {
        /* An edge is a connection between two nodes. It is represented by the parent
         * node and the directon to the child node. An edge may point to a null child.
         * There is also a special edge called the root edge which has the root as its
         * child, it is represented by a null parent. This representation allows us
         * to avoid writing duplicate code for handling operations involving the root.
         */
        public Node parent;
        public boolean direction;
        public Edge(Node parent, boolean direction)
        {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.direction = direction;
        }
        public Node child()
        {
            if(parent == null)
            {
                return root;
            }
            else
            {
                return parent.child(direction);
            }
        }
        public void setChild(Node child)
        {
            if(parent == null)
            {
                root = child;
            }
            else
            {
                parent.setChild(child, direction);
            }
        }
        public Node grandChild(boolean direction)
        {
            /* Returns the grandchild in the direction specified.
             * It is assumed this will not be called if the child
             * is null.
             */
            return child().child(direction);
        }
    }
    private class Path
    {
        /* A path is a list of adjacent edges going down the tree. All operations
         * are performed on the bottom-most edge of the path.
         */
        private Stack<Edge> stack;
        public Path(Edge edge)
        {
            stack = new LinkedListStack<Edge>();
            stack.push(edge);
        }
        public void push(boolean direction)
        {
            /* Extends the path downwards in the direction specified. It is
             * assumed this will not be called if the path points to a null
             * child.
             */
            stack.push(new Edge(child(), direction));
        }
        public Edge pop()
        {
            /* Retracts the bottom of the path upwards one edge and
             * returns the deleted edge.
             */
            return stack.pop();
        }
        public Edge peek()
        {
            return stack.peek();
        }
        public Node child()
        {
            return stack.peek().child();
        }
        public void setChild(Node child)
        {
            stack.peek().setChild(child);
        }
        public Node grandChild(boolean direction)
        {
            return stack.peek().grandChild(direction);
        }
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return toString(root, "", false);
    }
    public String toString(Node node, String prefix, boolean direction)
    {
        String string = "";
        if(node != null)
        {
            string += toString(node.right, prefix + (direction ? "        " : "│       "), true);
            string += prefix + (direction ? "┌─────" : "└─────") + String.format("(%s,%s)\n", node.key, node.value);
            string += toString(node.left, prefix + (direction ? "│       " : "        "), false);
        }
        return string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I'm going to start with what initially made me think the most, which is the fact that the height of a node is represented in two ways: Implicitly through the two subtrees of a node, and explicitly as an `int` field. Having interdependent state like this is always dangerous and makes code error prone, because a bug could cause the `int` field to contain a value different from the actual height of the node based on the structure of its subtrees. Replacing the field `height` with a method `height()` that recursively calculates the height based on the subtrees would make the code more robust and easier to hande. But of course, this would have a catastrophic impact on the performance, since updating the height values of a path would, if I'm not mistaken, be an \$O(\log_{2}n)\$ operation (with \$n\$ being the number of tree nodes, and \$\log_{2}n\$ therefore being the average depth), whereas recursively calculating the height of a node would require examining the complete subtrees, which would make it \$O(n)\$.

  So I think that, in this case, having interdependent state is justified. But for this, I would consider it all the more important to ensure that `height` never contains a wrong value by inseparably binding any modification of a node's `height` to a replacement of one of its child nodes, since the height of a node depends directly on the heights of its child nodes. Moreover, updating a node's height must also update the height of all of its ancestors as long as the height of a node changes due to the update.

  I see two ways to accomplish this. The most obvious way would be for each node to contain a reference not only to its children, but also to its parent, so that every time a node's child is replaced, it will update its own height and recursively cause its ancestors to update their height as well. The problem with this approach is that it would not only require more space, but also more time, because for each edge created or removed, an additional field has to be assigned. Furthermore, a rotation would then require three height update "waves", whereas one would suffice (starting from the new position of the rotated node). And since the whole point of this trouble is performance, solving the problem like this seems counterproductive.

  The other approach I can think of would be to define the methods for replacing a node's child not for a node, but only for an absolute path (i.e. making them methods of `Path` instead of `Node`). These methods would have to tamper directly with the fields `Node.left` and `Node.right`, but on the other hand, they can update the node's height and the height of all of its ancestors up to the root, if necessary (`updateHeights` could then also be a method of `Path`). And to avoid three update waves with rotations as mentioned in the previous paragraph, you could make `rotate` a bulk operation of `Path` that calls `updateHeights` only once after the rotation is complete, instead of making it a method of `AVLTreeDictionary`.
- A path as represented by your class `Path` can start anywhere. However, I could imagine that the code would be easier to handle if a path started at the root by definition. For one thing, this would make the change described in the previous point easier, and for another, it would solve the problem you yourself mentioned with having to write duplicate code for the root in a more elegant way than by introducing the concept of a "root edge", which to me seems more like a workaround than a solution, not least because the property `direction` of an edge is meaningless in the context of the root edge.

  The easiest way to implement this would probably to redesign the class `Edge` so that it stores not its parent, but its child. Then an empty path could be defined as pointing to the root. Your class `Edge` doesn't have any methods to access the parent node anyway, so maybe this would even improve overall readability.

  With an edge not having any reference to its parent, it will become impossible to make the parent node point to a different child using just the `Edge`. But this might actually not be a negative after all, because, taking into account what I've written in the previous point, changing a parent-child relationship without having the full path that leads from the root to these nodes would not be desirable anyway.
- In the class `AVLTreeDictionary`, the method `search(K)` duplicates most of the method `getPath(K)`. Why not simply call `getPath(K)` from within `search(K)` and extract the value from the destination node of the returned path?
- Speaking of the method `getPath(K)`, I would rewrite your `while(true)` loop to this:

  ```java
  int compare;
  while (path.child() != null
          && (compare = key.compareTo(path.child().key)) != 0) {
      path.push(compare > 0);
  }
  return path;
  ```

  Because now, the termination of the loop depends on its termination condition, which I think makes the code less confusing than if the loop is terminated from within.
- I find the method names involving the word "child" in your class `Path` confusing. "Child" only makes sense in the context of a node (and possibly an edge), but with a path, I would find something with "destination" more fitting, for example `nodeAtDestination()`, or simply `destination()`, because with the word "child", I automatically think of the child of the node the path points to, and I always have to think twice when trying to understand something like `somePath.child()` or `somePath.grandChild(someDirection)`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to review. I'll update my post with the changes you've suggested shortly. About the height updates, the complexity analysis of the AVL tree assumes that the rotate and setChild operations will run in constant time. Since a single one of these operations can cause O(log n) nodes to need adjustment of their height field I don't think it's possible to correct all heights each time they are called while maintaining constant time.

Comment: @GeorgeChiporikov What do you mean by "the complexity analysis of the AVL tree assumes that […]"? Of course, it will not be possible to maintain constant time for replacing a node's child when you have to update the height values. And you won't get around updating the height values if you rely on them. If you don't do it in `setChild`, you'll have to do it somewhere else (as you do it in `balancePath`). In the end, the time complexity will be the same. The only way to get child replacement to \$O(1)\$ would be to replace the field `height` with a method `height()` as I described in the […]

Comment: […] answer. But the price for this would be that querying the height of a node will be \$O(n)\$, whereas with the cached height values it is \$O(1)\$.

Comment: A single update to the tree can require O(log n) rotate/setChild calls. If I walk up the tree for each rotate/setChild call to adjust every height then that means a single rotate/setChild call will take O(log n) time. Since I need O(log n) rotate/setChild calls the total complexity of the balancePath method will be O((log n)^2). The problem with updating the heights from within rotate/setChild is that you end up updating the heights of the same nodes multiple times when rebalancing a path.

Comment: The balancePath method as I wrote it is able to perform only a single height update per rotation/setChild call because it doesn't need to correct any of the nodes above where it is working in order to perform its task. They will eventually be corrected once the balancePath method works its way to the top though.

Comment: @GeorgeChiporikov Ah yes, now I see what you mean. By the way, I already read and understood your first comment yesterday, but I simply had to go to sleep and was too tired to think about it :D. I think that, in the end, it boils down to the problem that it should be the caller's responsibility to cache values, and not the callee's. In this case, a way to model an AVL tree could be a simple binary tree at the core that doesn't care about the heights of its nodes and whether it is balanced. Then, there are the AVL-balancing specific methods which cache the heights of the nodes of the core […]

Comment: […] binary tree. The cleanest approach I can think of to implement this would be for the AVL "wrapper" to store a binary tree of its own that mimics the structure of the core binary tree and stores the cached height values. While this would probably greatly improve readability, as it clearly separates the responsibilities of node child replacement and tree balancing, it would probably be a bit slower and require much more space.

Comment: It just occurred to me that, instead of wrapping an entire binary tree and creating a "structural clone" from it, it would suffice to only wrap the tree entries in objects that, in addition to the entry, also store an `int` field for the cached node height. Then the AVL tree implementation could refer to the simple binary tree implementation to construct a tree holding these wrapper objects, and perform all of its balancing operations using this tree alone. I could imagine that the overhead from wrapping and unwrapping the original tree entries, both space- and time-wise, would be negligible.